# How to return value web from sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, wsgi

This is my code. I would like to show the values on the web. How would do it?

```
import sqlite3

def application(environ, start_response):

 db = sqlite3.connect('/root/example.db')
 db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute('''SELECT id, message,date FROM table''')
 for row in cursor:
  print('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row['id'], row['message'], row['date']))
 db.close()

 start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: @hakkikonu: the OP is using raw WSGI. You could make your comments a little more constructive by *explaining* why you are linking to other frameworks, but just dumping links isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of strings to return; printing writes to `stdout` and that is not returned to the browser.

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/root/example.db')
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT id, message,date FROM table''')

results = []
for row in cursor:
    results.append('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row['id'], row['message'], row['date']))
db.close()


headers = [
    ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
    ('Content-Length', str(sum(len(line) for line in results)))
]

start_response('200 OK', headers)

return results
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. It works.  Do you know how would do the same but showing the results in a table html <table><tr>the value </tr></table>?

Comment: @marcosbarcelona: include the HTML for a table in the output; `results = ['<table>']`, then for each row include your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, and append one final `</table>` string to the list.